# How to solve "docker touch: cannot touch ‘/var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log’: Permission denied"

Tags: jenkins

touch ‘/var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log’: Permission denied
Can not write to /var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log. Wrong volume permissions?

How to solve above permission issues?

Comment: I solved above issue by entering the command on server is chown -R 1000:1000 /opt/docker-mounts/jenkins

Answer (score 0):

I solved above issue by entering the command on server is

chown -R 1000:1000 /opt/docker-mounts/jenkins

/opt/docker-mounts/jenkins is the host path that we assigned in docker-compose.yaml file for /var/jenkins_home

example:

```
volumes:
  - /opt/docker-mounts/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home
```